Crystal Oscillator Waveform
I am learning to interpret oscilloscope readings and I have met an unusual waveform.
Have a look at the following PCB image.

It is a part of a guitar effect pedal.
When I put my probe on the left side of the crystal i get the following waveform:

It oscillates at a frequency of 12.2883Mhz as expected.
when I put my probe on the right side I get the following:

I do not understand why the waveform looks like this on the opposite side of the crystal.
There is another crystal on the PCB, an 8Mhz crystal, and it shows a nice sinusoidal waveform on both sides. Is the crystal malfunctioning or does the IC alter the waveform reading?

Is your question about the square wave shape of the second waveform?

What exactly disturbs you about these waveforms? They suggest a robustly-oscillating oscillator.

@sai yes, my question relates to the second waveform. Why would there be two different shapes coming from the same crystal. It does not happen to the other crystal.  There are a lot of answers and explanations in this thread. I will read them/

@vulubalulubalulu That's because the other waveform does not come from crystal but the chip. The crystal does not magically output two signals by itself.

It's not that unusual really. Depending on what you expect of course.
It's not the chip that alters the signal, rather it's the crystal. Or both, depending on viewpoint.
The oscillator amplifier inside the chip seems to have square wave output to crystal. You can think of it as sine wave amplified to clip, but it could also just be outputing square wave. Square waves have fast edges, they need a lot of bandwidth and if you probe poorly, the square wave edges will have under/overshoots.
Anyway, as the square wave enters the crystal, it passes only the fundamental frequency so sine wave comes out, goes into chip which amplifies it as output to crystal.
So crystal filters out the harmonics that make up the squarw wave, but the oscillator amplifier takes in the sine wave and outputs square out.
The crystal is definitely not malfunctioning, but doing what it is supposed to.
The chip just doesn't drive the crystal with sine but square. Some chips are like that.
The square wave comes from the chip to crystal. The sine wave comes from crystal to the chip.

I am assuming that your question is about the square shape of the second waveform. This is perfectly normal. There is an amplifier between the 2 oscillator pins (for eg., take a look at figure 2 in  https://ecsxtal.com/crystal-oscillator-design-application-note/ ) . The amplifier output could get clipped if the amplifier gain is high, hence, appearing as a square wave.
To reduce the output amplitude, one may reduce the amplifier gain using another loop (part of the circuit on the chip). In such a case, I think you'd get a sine wave at the output as well.

A few possible explanations:

Loading Effects and Probing Issues:

Probing the circuit itself can introduce capacitance and even small inductance, which can cause waveform distortion. On the right side of the crystal, if the signal is being fed into a high-impedance or sensitive input, your oscilloscope probe could be loading the circuit, causing a distorted waveform.
The right side might be directly connected to a high-gain input (like a clock buffer) that amplifies even small noise or signal instability.

IC Behavior and Feedback Loop:

The IC connected to the crystal might be part of a feedback loop to sustain oscillations. If you probe at a sensitive point, it might interfere with the feedback loop and cause the circuit to behave differently, leading to a distorted waveform.
The distortion might indicate that the circuit is not intended to be directly probed at that point, as the signal is not fully buffered or is in a transitional state.

Crystal Drive Level and Load Capacitance:

Crystals are sensitive to the drive level and the load capacitance. If the drive level is too high or low, the waveform can become unstable, especially on one side of the crystal. This could cause the distortion you’re seeing.
Given you're probing a PCB that has no engineering mistakes in it, it's probably the effect of your probe.

Long 10:1 probe grounds will resonate > 20 MHz. This is why all scopes have a 20 MHz LPF option.
It is a probe capture resonance error.
--- 
It is due to the ground wire inductance or ESL ~ 8nH/cm and the coax capacitance ~ 80 pF/m.  The proper probe method removes the probe tip and ground and samples the clk and gnd signals between tip and ring.  Do this to learn how ESL causes resonance and measure the frequency and ground path length to estimate your ESL/cm. This varies with the log of the wire or trace length/diameter ratio slightly.
I wrote about this long ago and learned it in 1975 when I started R&D using 200 MHz scopes.
For most Test Engineers a 3 cm ground clip is good enough but for textbook waveforms, you can use a coil spring probe adapter which is also a Tek accessory.
Scope probe having ringing with 10x option
